# Strange behavior iterating over lists with debugger

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, iterator

In the following code:

```
for (Iterator<MyClass> iterOuter = mList1.iterator(); iterOuter.hasNext();) {
    mClass1 = iterOuter.next();
    for (Iterator<MyClass> iterInner = mList2.iterator(); iterInner.hasNext();) {
        mClass2 = iterInner.next();
        if (...) {
            continue;
        }
        else if (...) {
            //code 1
        }
        else if (...) {
            continue;
        }
        else if (...) {
            //code 2
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: `code 1 & 2` are math calculation, in any moment ain't add or remove to the iterators.

When I inspect it with debugger I notice then after the last inner iteration, when I expect the debugger jump to the inner `for` line check the condition and then realize it's end of loop and jump back to outer `for` loop.

Instead after the inner `for` check (when the condition is not met and need to jump back to outer) the debugger jumps to the line with `//code 2` , NOT executing the code there and then jumps back to outer `for`.

What's happening here? Is this some issue with the debugger or it's something with java, the `if else if` structure with the `continue` etc?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza what you mean in consuming? I make calculation with `mClass1` but i'm not adding or removing elements to `iterOuter`. `code1 1 & 2` are just math calculation.

Comment: It seems strange, but with the code as is, this should not happen. Have you tried to isolate the problem and reproduce it in other method? Can you share that code here?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza This is the isolated code

Comment: This sounds like a known bug in the Java 1.6 debugger with enhanced for loops.  Are you by chance running this on a 1.6 VM? See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6807255

Comment: @JJF Thanks good point! I'm running on 1.8, I suspected it's some kind of "glidtch" in the debugger and not something wrong I'm doing.